# swift: unable to add core data to existing project - tried everything

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have tried all suggestions and solutions given in questions similar to mine, but i am still not able to add new core data to the existing project. Things i tried:

1. Added new core data file to a simple application project
2. Copied the core data file from older project that works
3. Created a blank new project with Core Data selected and then added all my files.
4. Modified/Updated/Cross checked AppDelegate several times.

But theres is one thing i have noted:

When i copy the core data file from older project to the current, it gives error as `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

whereas, when i make a new core data file, then there is a biggg error as shown below

```
CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/raunekk/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9CDAADD4-E413-4955-AF1B-9FBBB2B8E691/data/Containers/Data/Application/4FF507C8-9F5B-4982-B3B7-AAAF1F377FC0/Documents/MarineInsight.sqlite options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x7fc90b63eaf0 {metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "C8B3DC24-E463-4328-8459-56124E1E5B4D";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
 }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with
the one used to create the store} with userInfo dictionary {
 metadata =     {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "C8B3DC24-E463-4328-8459-56124E1E5B4D";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
     };
reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with 
the one used to create the store";
  }
2015-01-28 18:50:32.951 MarineInsight[8820:2204891] Unresolved 
 error      Optional(Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed 
 to    initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo=0x7fc90b420cd0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data., NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc90b63f510 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)"}), Optional([NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data., NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x7fc90b63eaf0 {metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "C8B3DC24-E463-4328-8459-56124E1E5B4D";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
   }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with 
 the one    used  to create the store}])
```

I am getting the Optional Value Error in AppDelegate in this function at line `let modelURL`

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Blog", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
    }()
```

I am at my wits end..plsssss plsss help me

Comment: Can you please post the code where you setup your persistent storage? It would also help if you could post the code on the line where you get the error about unwrapping an optional. The error tells you there's something returning a nil value.

Comment: Can you just delete you app from the simulator or device and try again with a new core data file?

Comment: @MarkusPersson updated the question to show the line getting error

Comment: @user3435374 i have already tried making a new app from scratch, added new core data which didnt work, also copied old core data but it also showed fatal error as mentioned in the question

Comment: Ok, so it seems it cannot find the .xcdatamodeld-file. Can you check so that the file is named "Blog.xcdatamodeld" and that the name is correct in "Identity and type" when you click on the file? Can you also make sure the file is included in the all the targets you need it (Target membership).

Comment: @MarkusPersson the name of my database was Blog.xcdatamodel .. the "d" at the end was missing.. sounds weird.. but tht solved the issue.. thank. :)

Comment: Ah, common mistake. Great that it works for you now!